# Jquery OneStarter for Salesforce 1 not functioning for close and disable submit

Tags: salesforce1-app, jquery

```
<apex:page standardController="Household__c" extensions="HouseholdPublisherActionExtension" showHeader="false">

<apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.OneStarter,'icons.css')}"/>
<apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.OneStarter,'styles.css')}"/>
<apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.OneStarter,'OneStarter.css')}"/>

<apex:includeScript value="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" />
<apex:includeScript value="//code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.0/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.min.js"/>

<apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.TouchSwipe,'jquery.touchSwipe.min.js')}"/>
<apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.OneStarter,'jquery.onestarter.js')}"/>
 <apex:includeScript value="/canvas/sdk/js/publisher.js"/>      

<script>
//this is implementation code
$(document).ready(
    function() {

        s1 = $('div#one-app').oneStarter('record-action').enableSubmit(

            function() {
                HouseholdPublisherActionExtension.createNote(
                    "{!Household__c.Id}",
                    function(res, mes) {
                        s1.disableSubmit();
                        s1.close();
                    }
                );
            }
        );
    }
);
```

```
<div id="form-example">
    <apex:form >
                <label class="field-label"><apex:outputText value="{!$ObjectType.Household__c.fields.Name.label}"/></label>
                <apex:inputField value="{!Household__c.Name}"/>

                <label class="field-label"><apex:outputText value="{!$ObjectType.Household__c.fields.Primary_Member__c.label}"/></label>
                <apex:inputField value="{!Household__c.Primary_Member__c}"/>

    </apex:form>
</div>
```

I am trying the above code but whats happening is after my callback i am getting issue as **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'disableSubmit'** of undefined  and the window is not closing .Any help here ?Or this is a bug currently in the framework?

Also using input field the lookup window did not popup ?Is this a bug ?

Comment: Mohith, just wondering why not use `$.noConflict();` here?

Comment: Let me try that too and get back to you

Comment: I've been playing with onestarter myself. I spoke to Josh about it the other day and he was sharing that another dev was having trouble getting it to play nicely with jQM. In addition to noconflict, you might try to pull out the jQM stuff you're doing and see if you get better luck.

Comment: AS @Peter mentions, definitely try it without jQM.  jQM does very odd things to DOM events for non-jQM frameworks, and I think it is possible doc.ready() is not firing as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thought is that I don't know if the s1 var here is getting set outside of the callback scope,  cannot call method of undefined makes me think it isn't.  Try setting it as a var outside doc.ready so that the callback sees the plugin's return object.

And definitely try it without jQM.  As Peter mentions in the comments, I've seen it create conflicts before.  It really likes to control the DOM event structure, so I can't promise that things are firing as expected if you're blending it in.

If you need a mobile-friendly framework to add new UI widgets like a modal window, try Bootstrap.  OneStarter might get updated with new UI widgets down the road.

This gist worked as expected for me:  https://gist.github.com/joshbirk/9842655

```
<apex:page standardController="Invoice__c" extensions="LineItemRemotingExtension" showHeader="false">

<apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.OneStarter,'icons.css')}"/>
<apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.OneStarter,'styles.css')}"/>
<apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.OneStarter,'OneStarter.css')}"/>

<apex:includeScript value="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" />
<apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.TouchSwipe,'jquery.touchSwipe.min.js')}"/>
<apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.OneStarter,'jquery.onestarter.js')}"/>
<apex:includeScript value="/canvas/sdk/js/publisher.js"/>      

<script>
s1 = {};

$(document).ready(
    function() {
        s1 = $('div#form-example').oneStarter('record-action');
        s1.enableSubmit(
            function() {
                LineItemRemotingExtension.getAccountRemote(
                    "Test",
                    function(res, mes) {
                        s1.disableSubmit();
                        s1.close();
                    }
                );
            }
        );
    }
);

</script>

<div id="form-example">
    <apex:form >
                <label class="field-label"><apex:outputText value="{!Invoice__c.Name}"/></label>
                <apex:inputField value="{!Invoice__c.Status__c}"/>

    </apex:form>
</div>

</apex:page>
```

Comment: .I tried to set outside document.ready and obtained error still.

Comment: OK, as noted in the answer and comments - try dropping jQM.

Comment: I commented the JQM as well and still the issue persists...

Comment: ok, let me try a similar scenario

Comment: np, updated the answer with a gist that panned out for me.

Comment: Thanks ..It worked ..so all the issue was using S1 as var

Comment: Yeah, it's a little unusual for jQuery plugin to work this way.  I might give it its own namespace or the like down the road to reduce the overhead.